# jQuery div element with same data attribute name, append to list

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to create a list of elements but I have an element that lives outside of the lists that gets populated with the same data attribute value, but I need to add my external element to another element with the same data attribute value.
The data attribute values are dynamically generated but I can guarantee that the 
data-groupnamefordescription and the data-groupname will out put the same for each group.

HTML

```
   <!--Elements that belong to the different groups below but render outside 
      each element.-->
  <div data-groupnamefordescription="Group1">Description for group 1</div>
  <div data-groupnamefordescription="Group2">Description for group 2</div>
  <div data-groupnamefordescription="Group3">Description for group 3</div>

 <!--Wrapper of elements that the description elements need to get put into 
   -->
 <div data-groupname="Group1"></div>
 <div data-groupname="Group2"></div>
 <div data-groupname="Group3"></div>
```

Need jQuery to put the group description elements into their respective groups.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT, added what I had as thus far for jQuery.

```
var groupdescript = $('div').data("groupnamefordescription");
    $.each(groupdescript , function(index, itemDesc) {
        $(this).appendTo($("div").data("groupname"));
    });
```

This did not work for me, this is why I was wondering.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why, seriously WHY is this down voted and voted to close.  How is anyone supposed to learn on this site?

Comment: That is simple, you haven't showed any effort of your own, no script is available ... and you _should_ know by now that that should be in the question ... and FYI, I didn't down vote

Comment: That's fine @LGSon, I, most of the time, post what I have tried.  But even when I have posted my full HTML and Javascript/jQuery in cases I still get down voted.  Even in more complex situations than my current question in which I am not familiar with.  People have legitimate questions.  Even if they are easy for some, it is not necessarily easy for others and in many cases, StackOverflow is a great resource, even if the are insanely simple solutions.  I try to contribute what I can when I can.  Even on simple solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector to target those elements and then `appendTo()`

```js
$('[data-groupnamefordescription]').each(function(){
  var group = $(this).data('groupnamefordescription');
  $(this).appendTo('[data-groupname="'+group+'"]');
})
```

```css
[data-groupname] {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: tomato
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-groupnamefordescription="Group1">Description for group 1</div>
<div data-groupnamefordescription="Group2">Description for group 2</div>
<div data-groupnamefordescription="Group3">Description for group 3</div>
<div data-groupnamefordescription="Group4">Description for group 4</div>

<div data-groupname="Group1"></div>
<div data-groupname="Group2"></div>
<div data-groupname="Group3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @DaniP that is exactly what I needed.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help U @ClosDesign